# Does <CassandraResult>.all() wipe data on use, while using Cassandra in Python?

Tags: python, cassandra

Table contents,

```
# Insert stuff into the table
query = 'insert into music_lib (year, artist_name, album_name) values (%s, %s, %s)'
try:
    session.execute(query, (2010, 'Linkin Park', 'A Thousand Suns'))
    session.execute(query, (2012, 'Linkin Park', 'Living Things'))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

My query is as such,

```
try:
    rows = session.execute('SELECT * FROM MUSIC_LIB')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

When I execute `rows.all()` for the first time, I get my result,

```
[Row(year=2010, artist_name='Linkin Park', album_name='A Thousand Suns'),
 Row(year=2012, artist_name='Linkin Park', album_name='Living Things')]
```

But when I execute `rows.all()` again, I get a blank output,
`[]`

Does the data get wiped upon call of rows.all()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing `session.execute`, then it returns the [`ResultSet` object](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/api/cassandra/cluster/#cassandra.cluster.ResultSet), that is iterator over data that is received from Cassandra, and these results are [paged](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/query_paging/). But the data is not stored in the memory for random access, so when you iterate, you skip to the next record, and may not return to previous one.

When you calling the `all` (it's dangerous for big datasets!), then it's basically calling `list(result_set)`, internally performing iteration over the all rows.  But when you call it second time, iterator is already exhausted, and you receive empty list.  To prevent that, you need to keep result of first call to `all` somewhere.

I recommend to go through [Getting Started](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/getting_started/) documentation, and read about best practices, such as, using prepared statements, etc. Also, please note that `select * from table` is anti-pattern for Cassandra, and most probably will hit you heavily when you get big enough dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!